# How do I force a variable to be initialized in a JavaFX object?

Tags: constructor, javafx

I am making a javaFX class and I need one of the variables to be initialized in order for it to work (in my program there's no default value I can use). This is the best I've come up with, but I'd like something that wont compile unless you initialize the variable.

Example Class:

```
Public class Class1{

    public-init var var1:String;

    postinit{
        if(var1 == null){
            println("You need to initialize var1");
        }
}
```

I'd call it like this:

```
var object1 = Class1{var1:"input"};
```

How can I prevent it from compiling if I do this?

```
var object1 = Class1{};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I think you have the best solution for forcing initialization. Only other thing you can do is set a default value:

```
public var var1: String = "BOGUS";
```

Comment: It occurs to me that I could throw an exception if the variable is not initialized. While that's still post-compile, it is at least a louder complaint.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
public class Class1 {
    public var var1: String = "" on replace{
                if (var1 == null) {
                    var1 = "";
                }
            };
}

var object1 = Class1{};
println(object1.var1);
object1.var1="HOLA :)";
println(object1.var1);
```

Output:

```
Mundo
HOLA
 :)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe:

```
public class Class1 {

    public-init var var1: String;

    init {
        if (var1 == null) { //or var1. length() == 0 ) {
            println("You need to initialize var1");
            Stage {
                title: "Ups!!!"
                onClose: function() {
                }
                scene: Scene {
                    content: [
                        Label {
                            text: "You need to initialize var1"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

[image]